# #pragma comment (lib, "libinfinityhook") not working for release version of this library

Tags: visual-studio

I've downloaded the [infinityHook](https://github.com/everdox/InfinityHook) open source project compiled it successfully (both release and debug compilations) in VS2017 Community on Windows 8.1. Now I'm trying to link the libinfinityhook.lib file using the #pragma comment directive in my project as follows:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "libinfinityhook")
```

I've manually copied the debug build of libinfinityhook.lib to a custom directory and added this entire path to **Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Libraries Directories**. The funny thing now is the debug version of this library works but the release version does not. The release build of my project gives a unresolved error (see below). If someone can suggest what I am doing wrong with this configuration I would appreciate it.

```
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol IfhInitialize referenced in function DriverEntry
```

If I add the exact same library (release) through the solution explorer as a source files in my project as seen in the following screenshot the project compiles and builds successfully.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found the error I was making. As per the Microsoft article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-170) the linker searches first in the current working directory, and then in the path specified in the LIB environment variable. However I did not place the lib file in any of the directories as stated in lib environment variable nor in the current working directory.